# Sun's Mesh Denoise algorithm not working (feature preserving smoothing)

Tags: raster, gdal, elevation, srtm, smoothing

I tried to use [Sun's denoise](https://github.com/exuberant/mdenoise) algorithm for elevation data via the [RCP project from Jake](https://gisjake.blogspot.com/2018/10/rasterchunkprocessingpy-installation.html) but I cannot observe any changes to the TIF file:

```
python raster_chunk_processing.py -m mdenoise -t 0.9 -n 10 -v 50 -s 1500 -o 25 srtm_39_03.tif srtm_39_03_denoise.tif
```

I downloaded the elevation TIF file from CGIAR ([download it here](https://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/wp-content/uploads/files/srtm_5x5/TIFF/srtm_39_03.zip) and unzip). I visualized the file using gdaldem:

```
gdaldem color-relief srtm_39_03.tif color-relief.txt srtm_39_03_color.tif
```

Where color-relief.txt is:

```
-32767,100,0,0
0,0,20,255
100,60,70,250
200,122,255,160
500,0,170,52
900,240,255,63
1200,255,195,63
1500,255,130,63
1800,255,98,63
2100,255,72,63
2600,255,63,203
3000,180,180,180
3600,white
```

Now when I compare the original TIF file with the produced TIF file (using `gdaldem color-relief`) I cannot see any differences, i.e. it has no effect!? And using a different method like `-m blur_gauss` I can see a difference. Also using the [mdenoise tool](https://github.com/exuberant/mdenoise) directly does not lead to a difference. And I had the same problem that nothing changes with a [completely different implementation of mdenoise](https://github.com/karussell/fp_denoise).

What did I do wrong for `-m mdenoise`? Maybe I use a wrong projection like described [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/saga-gis/discussion/790705/thread/7b706af2/)? But not sure yet how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I somehow have to convert the lat,lon into the same unit as the elevation, i.e. into meters as written [here](https://wanderingcartographer.wordpress.com/2021/04/30/making-shaded-relief-directly-from-dems-projected-in-degrees/):

> you don’t need to re-project your DEMs before making shaded relief. Instead, I said, you can just use the magic scaling number 111120 to convert from degrees to metres.

and also indicated [here](https://github.com/jblindsay/fp_denoise):

> Note that the input DEM should be in a projected coordinate system (e.g. UTM) and in a Whitebox GAT or ArcGIS ASCII raster format.

But I couldn't get it working with gdal_translate or gdalwarp. Maybe someone can still solve this mystery for me :)

Instead I used yet another implementation from the [whitebox repository](https://github.com/jblindsay/whitebox-tools/blob/master/whitebox-tools-app/src/tools/terrain_analysis/feature_preserving_smoothing.rs) successfully:

```
./target/release/whitebox_tools -r=FeaturePreservingSmoothing -i srtm_39_03.tif -o ./out/srtm_39_03_whitebox.tif
```

See [documentation](https://www.whiteboxgeo.com/manual/wbt_book/available_tools/geomorphometric_analysis.html#featurepreservingsmoothing) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FM3It51L7ZA).